# Naming .net namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, naming-conventions, naming

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Middleware and am concerned about the namespace naming. I'm planning on use AspNetCore.MyMiddlewareName and I would like to publish it in Nuget but not sure if I'm allowed to use that "AspNetCore" part of the name.

So, basically, my question is: Is there any statement that prohibits me to use "AspNetCore" as part of the namespace used in the package I want to publish?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is anything that would explicitly prevent you from using that name, but I would recommend against it.  It does not do anything to describe what your middleware actually does.  If "MyMiddlewareName" describes what the middleware does, then there is really no reason to add AspNetCore at the beginning.

Comment: I'm using it to stick with the Microsoft namespace naming guidelines that's described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026(v=vs.110).aspx). It recommends that namespace names should follow this scheme `<Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]`. Since I'm not a company I'm omitting that part.

Comment: I would use either my last name or a username (like manyrdz).  I think if you use AspNetCore, people will be confused or suspicious, as it would sound like you are trying to make it appear that your component is a part of Microsoft.  Typically, when I think of the "technology" piece of namespace, like in the article you referenced", I think of something more generic like "web".

Comment: That's true, I better add the Company part to avoid any inconvenience.